# dataTables custom filtering by class name of <tr>

Tags: jquery, datatables

I read the documentation at http://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html for filtering by a range, but I don't quite understand how to filter items by a row's class.

I want to have a several buttons that when clicked, filter the dataTable by the classes (string values) of each row. So for example, if you have

```
<tr class="dont_filter">
<tr class="do_filter">
```

They would both show up by default. When someone clicks one of the buttons, all rows with "do_filter" are hidden, and dataTables redraws the list so that this change occurs throughout all pages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a fork of a datatables fiddle that was used for something entirely different.

http://jsfiddle.net/72xGx/

This sample takes the 'range filtering' example on the datatables site as a starting point. 
It uses checkboxes to determine if a filter should be applied, and all filters are on by default. As you check and un-check the checkboxes, they data in the table should accordingly filter. No doubt this could stand some cleaning up, but I believe you will find it is one route to accomplish your stated goal.

**JavaScript**

```
/* Custom filtering function which will filter data in column four between two values */
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(

function (oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
    var gA = $('#ckb-gradeA').is(':checked'),
        gC = $('#ckb-gradeC').is(':checked'),
        gU = $('#ckb-gradeU').is(':checked'),
        gX = $('#ckb-gradeX').is(':checked');

    var myRowClass = oSettings.aoData[iDataIndex].nTr.className;

    if (myRowClass === 'gradeA' || myRowClass === 'gradeA even' || myRowClass === 'gradeA odd') {
        return gA === true ? true : false;
    } else if (myRowClass === 'gradeC' || myRowClass === 'gradeC even' || myRowClass === 'gradeC odd') {
        return gC === true ? true : false;
    } else if (myRowClass === 'gradeU' || myRowClass === 'gradeU even' || myRowClass === 'gradeU odd') {
        return gU === true ? true : false;
    } else if (myRowClass === 'gradeX' || myRowClass === 'gradeX even' || myRowClass === 'gradeX odd') {
        return gX === true ? true : false;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});

$(function () {
    /* Initialise datatables */
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();

    /* Add event listeners to the two range filtering inputs */
    $('#ckb-gradeA').change(function () {
        oTable.fnDraw();
    });
    $('#ckb-gradeC').change(function () {
        oTable.fnDraw();
    });
    $('#ckb-gradeU').change(function () {
        oTable.fnDraw();
    });
    $('#ckb-gradeX').change(function () {
        oTable.fnDraw();
    });
});
```

**part of the html table structure**
(so as to note some of the `css` classes on the `<tr>` elements)

```
    <tr class="gradeC">
        <td>Trident</td>
        <td>Internet Explorer 5.0</td>
        <td>Win 95+</td>
        <td class="center">5</td>
        <td class="center">C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gradeA">
        <td>Trident</td>
        <td>Internet Explorer 5.5</td>
        <td>Win 95+</td>
        <td class="center">5.5</td>
        <td class="center">A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gradeA">
        <td>Trident</td>
        <td>Internet Explorer 6</td>
        <td>Win 98+</td>
        <td class="center">6</td>
        <td class="center">A</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Thanks for this - `oSettings.aoData[iDataIndex].nTr.className;` was the missing piece of the jigsaw for me.  Couple of notes:  i think you're missing the `);` for the `$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(` - should be before `$(function () {`.  Also, in case anyone else (like me) is using DataTables 1.10 onwards, you need to call `table.draw()` rather than `table.fnDraw()` to make the table refresh itself.

Comment: Also, a cleaner way to test the class is to split it into an array of classnames and see if that array contains the class you're testing.  So, you can say `var myRowClasses = oSettings.aoData[iDataIndex].nTr.className.split(" ");` and then test like `if(myRowClasses.indexOf('gradeA') > -1)`